# Stored procedure variable declarations

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Just wondering what is the different between these two stored procedure declarations?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_name] 
     @mainSorsTbl NVARCHAR(50), 
     @mainSorsClmn NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @fromTable NVARCHAR(50), 
     @fromColumn NVARCHAR(MAX), 
     @toTable NVARCHAR(50), 
     @toColumn NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
   ....
```

and this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CopyScDestDevByVendor]
     (@var1 VARCHAR(15),  
      @var2 VARCHAR(8),  
      @var2 VARCHAR(20),  
      @var4 VARCHAR(8),  
      @var5 VARCHAR(3),  
      @INT = 0 OUTPUT) 
AS
    ......
```

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: im using sql server

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have brackets around the parameters in the first one:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_name] @mainSorsTbl nvarchar(50), @mainSorsClmn nvarchar(max),@fromTable nvarchar(50), @fromColumn nvarchar(max), @toTable nvarchar(50), @toColumn nvarchar(max)
as
begin....
```

Needs to be:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_name]
( @mainSorsTbl nvarchar(50), @mainSorsClmn nvarchar(max),@fromTable nvarchar(50), @fromColumn nvarchar(max), @toTable nvarchar(50), @toColumn nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin....
```

otherwise it won't work

Also ALTER will only work if the procedure exists already.

A work around for newer versions of SQL is to use

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE sprocname
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your comment, actually I just wondering what's the different between those 2? one contain param with bracket and the others none.

Comment: `CREATE OR ALTER` is available from SQL Server **2016** on

Comment: There is no requirement to enclose the parameters in parentheses.

Comment: The Alter procedure includes an Output parameter as well